# Legend on top of a pst-solides3d drawing

Tags: pstricks, 3d

Another question about`pst-solides3d` and visibility:

How can one draw a legend on top of the 3d drawings ?

I thought that putting the `put` command before or after the 3d drawings commands would render the text in the foreground, but with both ways, the text is hidden:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(0,-3)(7,3)

\psset{viewpoint=60 30 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,lightsrc=viewpoint, solidmemory}

\Large
\rput(0.5,2.7){$x^2$}
\normalsize

\psSolid[object=cylindre, h=0.4,r=2.7, fillcolor=white, ngrid=1 32, RotY=0, RotX=0] (0,0,1.1445)

\Large
\rput(0,2.7){$x^2$}
\normalsize

\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compilation: `latex bug.tex; dvips bug.dvi; ps2pdf bug.ps`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way out is to include `pst-3dplot` package and then use `\pstThreeDPut` command.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(0,-3)(7,3)

\psset{viewpoint=60 30 30 rtp2xyz,Decran=60,lightsrc=viewpoint, solidmemory}

\psSolid[object=cylindre, h=0.4,r=2.7, fillcolor=white, ngrid=1 32, RotY=0, RotX=0]     (0,0,1.1445)

\Large
\pstThreeDPut(0,2.7,2.5){$x^2$}

\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```